# HttpURLConnection method is always GET?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

As the Android documents indicate, I've set `setDoOutPut(true);` so that the connection sends as `POST`. However, in the debugger when I check the `HTTPURLConnection` method member, it is always `GET`, even after setDoOutput(true) and even `setRequestMethod("POST")`. Am I somehow resetting it back to `GET`?

```
URL url = new URL(serverAddr);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setRequestMethod(verb);
urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(postBody.getBytes().length);
//urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", postBody.getBytes().toString());
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");

urlConnection.connect();

OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
out.write(postBody.getBytes());
out.flush();

int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("HTTPS RESPONSE CODE: " + responseCode);

out.close();
```

EDIT: This has got to be a bug...the debugger shows setDoOuput member variable clearly as false even when I'm setting it to true. It's not being set!

Comment: What is `verb` ? And have you verified that it in fact makes a GET request and not a POST?

Comment: verb is being passed in with value "POST". How can I verify this? The response code is returning 400, but I'm not sure if it's a bad GET request or a bad POST request.

Comment: Try the following `URL url = new URL(address);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", ...);
                OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "utf-8"));
                writer.write(requestBody);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                outputStream.close();`

Comment: for me bugged in JDK1.8 but perfectly working on JDK11

Comment: Folks, this was my post many years back. If you are reading this, use Retrofit! Don't use native http unless you have to!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `urlConnection.setDoInput(true);` if you wish to use POST verb and send data with your request.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setDoInput(boolean)

It must be set before connection is established.

Comment: Doesn't work. The docs say: "To upload data to a web server, configure the connection for output using setDoOutput(true)."

Comment: As per doc, it is set true by default

Comment: I think he meant `urlConnection.setDoOutput(true)` the input stream is actually used to receive the data from the server while the output stream is for sending data to the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working example:

```
    url = new URL(requestURL);

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);


    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    os.close();
    int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
    Map<String, List<String>> mp = conn.getHeaderFields();

    if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        String line;
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
            response+=line;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm experiencing a very strange problem. I've used the debugger to step through setDoOutput(true). I can see that the member variable is being set to true, but the moment the program steps outside of that method, doOutput is still false! What is going on here?

Comment: That's very strange. Can you try the order of conn calls in my code snippet? First set the requets method, and then set the input and output.

Comment: Just tried it. Same thing. doOutput is always false. even with setRequestMethod("POST") the method is always "GET".

Comment: anything on this? I'm facing the same problem on Marshmallow

Comment: @ÁbrahámEndre Were you able to figure this out? I'm still stuck on this. Always sending GET.